# PHP session gets regenerated on every request : CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, codeigniter-3, fedora

Though this is the most asked question, none of the solutions worked for me.

Here problem is, session is getting regenerated on every request in my project site on localhost.
I'm in db session, where new entry is seen on each request (as well as the cookie), which is not allowing users to login without giving any error.

- There is no problem with `session_start` as I'm using session library.
- I tried changing sessions configurations but it doesn't work.
- Other sites on my host are working fine with sessions.
- **Working copy** of site running on server also giving the same **problem** in localhost
- I tried to go back to my old version using `git`, that also produces the same problem.

**Current config:**

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'database';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = '_usr';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 0;   // tried changing this
$config['sess_save_path'] = '_sessions_web';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 0;  // this too
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = TRUE;

$config['cookie_prefix']    = '';
$config['cookie_domain']    = '';
$config['cookie_path']      = '/';
$config['cookie_secure']    = FALSE;
$config['cookie_httponly']  = FALSE;
```

**Tried adding this too:**

```
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 30*60); // expires in 30 minutes
```

> Earlier, everything was working fine but looks like this started after upgrading Fedora 25 to 26.

What can be the reason that can cause such problem?
Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Have you checked your cookie settings? If you have secure cookies only and you are accessing your site from HTTP then the session will regenerate on every request

Comment: Where to see that?
In my server. site is on http only. but same code works fine. 
In localhost, phpMyAdmin is working fine (it can have consistent cookie)

Comment: It is in the config file below the session variables

Comment: That setting is fine. Already `cookie_secure` is false

Comment: same issue here. and still I can't find any good reason / answer to resolve this problem. Working fine on server but issue on localhost. While my core projects are working fine on local with session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

J Shubham!

I just updated the session library with latest one. I have updated these files:

> 1. System/Session/Session.php
> 2. System/Session/Session_driver.php
> 3. System/Session/drivers/Session_files_driver.php

This tricked worked for me on localhost.